# Problems with updating to Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am updating Rails and followed the instructions on this site: http://railsapps.github.io/updating-rails.html

```
$ rvm use ruby-2.1.5@rails4.2 --create
$ gem install rails
$ rails -v
```

However, after running `rails -v`, my version was still 4.1.5.

I typed gem list next and got this for rails: 
    rails (4.2.0, 4.1.8, 4.1.5)
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.5)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.1)

and then after `rails -v`, I still got 4.1.5.

I tried Googling, but there were no answers. I am wondering what's going on.

Comment: What does `which rails` return?

Answer (score 0):

So, in your gemset, you want to see only rails v. 4.2.0? Just type `gem uninstall rails` and delete v. 4.1.8 and v. 4.1.5(you will be prompted to chose which version to uninstall).

Answer (score 0):

To switch at any time to the ruby you have selected as default:

```
$ rvm default
```

**Example:**

1) To show what ruby is currently the selected default, if any, do:

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

 * ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p481 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

2) switch to ruby:

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p481
```

3) set default

```
 $ rvm default
```

4) or use

```
rvm --default use 2.0.0
```

https://rvm.io/rubies/default